# Issue with svn+ssh changing the svn username for the same ssh user connection

Tags: svn, ssh, tortoisesvn, putty

I've got a problem to change my svn username within the ssh connection. I need to change the svn username inside the same ssh connection. I've got an svn repository accessed by many users by ssh connection using the same username. However, during the svn operations, I need to change the svn username avoiding the operations register for a unique user. I'm using the tortoise to do the svn checkout through the Putty ssh connection. 
My Tortoise checkout string is:
`svn+ssh://[ssh_username]@[putty_connection_name]/home/path_to/svn_repo`

Therefore, for each Working copy, I will use the same [ssh_username] for the connection, but the svn operations must be executed with other usernames.
Is it possible? How can I do that?

Thank you for your help.